# Assigning a pointer to const data to another pointer

Tags: c++

I am having hard time to understand the following behaviour

```
int main(void) 
{ 
    const int a1 = 40; 
    const int* b1 = &a1; 
    int* c1 = (int*)b1; // compiler gives error without the cast
    *b1 = 75; // gives read only error as expected 
    *c1 = 65; // This works fine
    
    cout<< a1 << *b1 << *c1;
    return 0; 
}
```

I couldn't find exact question so please close this and point to the answer if it already exists.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.  It neither "works" nor "doesn't work" because there is no "correct" or "incorrect" behavior.  Anything can happen.

Comment: Whenever you feel the need to do a C-style explicit conversion (like you do with the cast `(int*)b1`) you should take that as a sign that you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: For reasoning why this isn't allowed: If you have a variable which is `const`, then you shouldn't modify it. Putting it into a non-`const` lets you modify it, essentially making `const` useless.

Comment: Any time you see a cast (like `(int*)` it is telling the compiler to shut up and accept whatever the programmer is trying to do, silencing its ability to normally help you avoid errors like writing to a constant object. The reason you don't get an error with `*c1` is because you explicitly told the compiler not to tell you about that error when you used `(int*)`.

Comment: To be clear: the issue isn't the C-style cast (`(int*)b1`); it's the cast itself. `const_cast<int*>(b1)` would have exactly the same problem. `a1` is not supposed to be modified; the cast and the subsequent use of the pointer tells the compiler to pretend that `a1` actually is modifiable. Pretending doesn't make it true.

Comment: Note that C++ allows you to write a lot of code that compiles, but still is not correct. Also if you are new to C++ I would recommend not to focus too much on pointer use (and misuse). Because even without pointers you can get the same behavior when you cast away constness of a variable.

Comment: Imagine that you have read only memory (e.g. a code page with read only flag on a modern CPU, or really ROM in firmware). C++ can decide at compile time to put your const variables there, becuase you said its const... and even casting away const will not make the memory writable by magic and then what... your program would be incorrect anyway. This is one of the reasons C++ has Undefined Behavior, it allows the compiler to make choices depending on the hardware and YOU should not try to work around that.

Comment: Back in the old days, doing stuff like this was a common cause of a runtime "Bus Error".